MAMP using wrong PHP version
I'm running MAMP 7.0 with PHP version 8.3.9 selected.

I have PHP 8.3.9 in the PATH and which php returns the correct version.
~ % echo $path
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.3.9/bin /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql57/bin [other stuff that's not PHP related]
~ % which php 
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.3.9/bin/php

And yet anything in MAMP's htdocs folder is using the other version listed in MAMP's PHP selector, 8.2.20. phpinfo shows that it's loading from /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.20.
What's going on?
Update 2024.10.30: Mamp holds separate versions of php.ini for each available version of PHP, located at /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.3.9/conf/php.ini and /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.20/conf/php.ini. phpinfo confirms that it is loading the version from /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.2.20/conf.
To clarify, I am using the free version of Mamp, which appears to have a different configuration to Mamp Pro.

Quick feedback : Did you check the php.ini ? (typically it is something like /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini)

@KenLee Maybe the options are different in Mamp Pro, but each php version here seems to have it's own php.ini.
